# PowerShell script to concatenate regex and variable

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to write PowerShell script and regex to audit several network devices configuration files for compliance.  Some devices are configured one management vlan while others have multiple different management vlans.  Examples below

Config1:

```
VLAN    Name              Status     Ports
1       default           active         
100     12_NET_MGMT_VLAN  active     Gi1/2
```

Config2:

```
VLAN    Name              Status     Ports
1       default           active
88      100_MGMT-VLLAN    active     Gi8/1
100     12_Net_MGMT_VLAN  active
```

If I hard code the regex pattern like this `$regex_pattern = "^\d{1,3}\s+.*MGMT.*"`, I got the corrected output as expected

```
Config1 12_NET_MGMT_VLAN
Config2 100_MGMT_VLAN
Config2 12_Net_MGMT_VLAN
```

Instead of hard-code the regex pattern, I want to use the `Read-Host` cmdlet and ask a user to enter the word "MGMT" and store it in a variable `$Mgmt`, then concatenate with a regex pattern to create a dynamic regex pattern, like this:

```
$Mgmt = Read-Host "Enter a word pattern to find a management vlan: "
```

For example, a user type in `MGMT`, and then I created a dynamic regex pattern as below:

```
$regex_pattern = "^\d{1,3}\s+.*"+$Mgmt+"_.*" 
$regex_pattern = "^\d{1,3}\s+.*"+[regex]::escape($Mgmt)+".*"
```

None of the results came out correct

If anyone has a solution, please help. Thx

Comment: "None of the results came out correct" take a look at the value of `$regex_pattern` after you've constructed it from `$Mgmt`, and compare it to the value it has when you hard code it

Comment: I typed it wrong, sorry

Comment: No worries - you should post an answer below if you figured out the solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

If we are to assume that VLAN names cannot contain spaces, you can use `\S` (non-space) as an anchor character. Using the [subexpression operator](http://100_MGMT-VLLAN%2012_Net_MGMT_VLAN) `$()`, you can evaluate an expression within a string.

```
# Simulating a vlan config output
$Config = @'
VLAN    Name              Status     Ports
1       default           active
88      100_MGMT-VLLAN    active     Gi8/1
100     12_Net_MGMT_VLAN  active   
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# Using value MGMT here when prompted
$Mgmt = Read-Host "Enter a word pattern to find a management vlan"
$regex = "\S*$([regex]::Escape($Mgmt))\S*"
[regex]::Matches($Config,$regex).Value
```

**Output:**

```
100_MGMT-VLLAN
12_Net_MGMT_VLAN
```

Note that simple variable references like `$Mgmt` will expand properly within surrounding double quotes, e.g. `"My VLAN is $Mgmt"`.

---

You *could* take this in a different direction and create a custom object from your output. This would enable you to use filtering via `Where-Object` and member access (`.Property`) to retrieve target data. This again assumes values don't contain spaces.

```
# Simulating a vlan config output
$Config = @'
VLAN    Name              Status     Ports
1       default           active
88      100_MGMT-VLLAN    active     Gi8/1
100     12_Net_MGMT_VLAN  active   
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$Mgmt = Read-Host "Enter VLAN Name"
# Replacing consecutive spaces with , first
$ConfigObjs = $Config -replace '\s+',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
$ConfigObjs
```

Output:

```
VLAN Name             Status Ports
---- ----             ------ -----
1    default          active
88   100_MGMT-VLLAN   active Gi8/1
100  12_Net_MGMT_VLAN active
```

Now you have properties that can be referenced and access to other comparison operators so you don't always need to use regex.

```
($ConfigObjs | Where Name -like "*$Mgmt*").Name
```

Output:

```
100_MGMT-VLLAN
12_Net_MGMT_VLAN
```

Comment: I tried both solutions but didn't get the expected result